# Click (on <input>) refreshing current page and not forwarding to next page (Watir-Webdriver)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am having an issue on **watir-webdriver(MacOSX 10.10.3)** in **Firefox** with clicking a confirm button **(input tag)** after filling out a commerce form. My commerce form has a submit button **(input tag)** where a click works fine and forwards me to my confirmation page, but once I click the confirm button to process a transaction the page just refreshes and does not forward me to my next page(receipt). Upon clicking the confirm button **"$("overlay_29").show(); and $("processing_29").show();"** run and briefly shows me my screen that to transaction is processing then the page refreshes and nothing happens. I have tried the process manually and my pages work fine and everything works the way it is suppose to.

I have researched this issue for about a week now and read and implemented every topic that covers click issues, waiting for DOM, fire_event, execute_script, native_event on or off. I am a little stumped on this one and would appreciated any help.

I have tried all of these methods to click:

```
b = @browser
b.button(:src=> /btn_confirm/).click
b.button(:src=> /btn_confirm/).when_present.click
b.button(:src=> /btn_confirm/).fire_event "onclick"
b.input(:src=> /btn_confirm/).click
b.input(:src=> /btn_confirm/).when_present.click
b.input(:src=> /btn_confirm/).fire_event "onclick"
```

When I run these methods they all come out true:

```
b = @browser
puts b.button(:src=> /btn_confirm/).exists?
puts b.button(:src=> /btn_confirm/).enabled?
puts b.button(:src=> /btn_confirm/).visible?
```

I have tried the following watir-webdriver versions

```
0.6.4-0.7.0
```

I have tried every single release of Firefox that is not beta from v17-v38 with each watir-webdriver gem --version with no success.

This is the form html:

```
    <!-- Generated Form CSS Start name="Confirm Payment Details" -->

    <style type="text/css">


    </style>

    <!-- Generated Form CSS End name="Confirm Payment Details" -->

    <!-- Generated Form HTML Start name="Confirm Payment Details" -->
    <div id="twodialog_commerce_form_wrapper_5" class="commForm1 twodialog_form_wrapper twodialogEditableElement">
        <h2 id="twodialog_commerce_form_description" class="twodialog_form_description twodialogEditableElement">Confirm Payment Details</h2>


        <form class="twodialog_form twodialogEditableElement" id="commerce_5" name="commerce_5" target="_self" action="https://secure.2dialog.com/mt5/main.php/micro_sites/showpage/id/1/page_number/2" method="POST">
            <input id="CommerceID" name="CommerceID" value="5" type="hidden">
            <input name="widget_id" value="29" type="hidden">

            <div id="twodialog_form_cart_wrapper" class="twodialog_form_cart">
              <h2 class="twodialog_form_cart_description">Your Donation</h2>


    <table id="twodialog_form_cart_table" class="twodialog_form_cart_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>

          <th class="title_item" style="width: 75%;">Item</th>
          <th class="title_amount">Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr class="cartItem cartItemOneTime rowEven" id="cartRow2">

            <td class="name">
                <b>$10.00 Donation.</b><br>
                <i>Donate $10.00.</i>
            </td>
            <td class="cost">
                $10.00
                <br><a href="#" onclick="removeCartItem('/mt5/main.php/micro_sites/', 2, 'one_time',0, 0); return false;">remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cartItem cartItemOneTime rowOdd" id="cartRow3">

            <td class="name">
                <b>$20.00 Donation.</b><br>
                <i>Donate $20.00.</i>
            </td>
            <td class="cost">
                $20.00
                <br><a href="#" onclick="removeCartItem('/mt5/main.php/micro_sites/', 3, 'one_time',0, 0); return false;">remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="cartEmpty cartEmptyOneTime" colspan="2" style="display: none" align="center">Your cart is empty</td></tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1" class="alignRight total_label"><label>Total:</label></td>
          <td class="total_value">$30.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
            </div>


      <h2 id="twodialog_form_commerce_description" class="twodialog_form_description twodialogEditableElement">Credit Card Information</h2>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_wrapper" class="twodialog_form_commerce twodialogEditableElement">
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_type_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement odd">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_type_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">Card Type<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_type_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        Visa

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_number_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement even">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_number_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">Card Number<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_number_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        ***********4290

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_cvv_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement odd">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_cvv_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">CVV<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_cvv_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        ***

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_expiration_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement even">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_expiration_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElementl">Expiration<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_expiration_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        6/2015

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_name_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement odd">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_name_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">Name on Card<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_card_name_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        DonFN DonLN

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_address_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement even">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_address_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">Address<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_address_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        123 Fruitful Ln

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_city_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement odd">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_city_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">City<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_city_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        New York

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_state_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement even">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_state_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">State / Province<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_state_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        <span id="CCDetails_State" class="twodialogEditableElement">NY</span>

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_postal_code_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement odd">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_postal_code_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">Postal Code<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_postal_code_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        12345

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_country_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement even">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_country_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">Country<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_country_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        <span id="CCDetails_Country" class="twodialogEditableElement">United States</span>

      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_phone_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement odd">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_phone_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">Phone</label>



      </div>
      <div id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_email_row" class="twodialog_form_item_list_row twodialogEditableElement even">
        <label id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_email_label" class="twodialog_form_label twodialogEditableElement">Email Address<span id="twodialog_form_commerce_billing_email_required_symbol" class="twodialog_form_required twodialogEditableElement">*</span></label>

        donfnln@mail.com

      </div>
      </div>
            <p id="twodialog_form_control_5" class="twodialog_form_control twodialogEditableElement"><input class="twodialog_form_button_confirm processorButton_29 zaptastic twodialogEditableElement twodialogEditableElement" name="commit" src="https://secure.2dialog.com/mt5/images/btn_confirm.png" alt="&nbsp;" id="twodialog_confirmation_submit_button" value="" onclick=";" type="image">&nbsp;<input class="twodialog_form_button_change twodialogEditableElement twodialogEditableElement" name="cancel" src="https://secure.2dialog.com/mt5/images/btn_change.png" alt="change" id="twodialog_confirmation_cancel_button" value="change" onclick=";" type="image">
        </p>


        <div class="processorOverlay" id="overlay_29" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="processorMessage" id="processing_29" style="display: none">
          Please wait while we process your credit card.
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<!-- Generated Form HTML End name="Confirm Payment Details" -->

<!-- Generated Form JS Start name="Confirm Payment Details" -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    Event.observe(document, "dom:loaded", function(){

      getCurrentStateLabel("/mt5/main.php/micro_sites/", "COM", function(label){
          $("CCDetails_State").update(label);
      });
      getCurrentCountryLabel("/mt5/main.php/micro_sites/", "COM", function(label){
          $("CCDetails_Country").update(label);
      });


    if(true)
    {
        $$(".processorButton_29").each(function(element){
            element.observe("click", function(event){
                $("overlay_29").show();
                $("processing_29").show();
            });
        });
    }

    });
</script>

<!-- Generated Form JS End name="Confirm Payment Details" -->
```

Comment: You specifically mentioned that the problem is in Firefox. Does that mean that it works fine in other browsers (ex Chrome)? I know there is at least one difference between how Firefox and Chrome click elements (though unlikely to be related to your problem).

Comment: Yes @JustinKo it works fine in Chrome. It is just in Firefox where it does not work.

Comment: Does it work if you target the `id` of the same field with `:id => "twodialog_confirmation_submit_button"`?

Comment: No it does not work if I target `id` either. I have tried all the attributes on that **input** tag.